# Splitting file content into other files based on parsed parameter value in file

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

A regular file contains data organized in columns, separated by space. Based on the value of the second field, I want to split that initial data file into several other files.

The data file has 54,242 rows and 399 columns. Data structure is so:

```
SNP Chr Pos ID_01 ID_02 ...
rs01 1 200 AA BB ...
rs02 25 10 BA AA ...
rs03 1 30 AA BB ...
rs04 X 90 BB AA ...
```

My output should consist of each record (or row) in as many `file"${chr}"` as there are different `$chr` values in column 2. So for example:

**file1** will contain all the records whose 2nd field is `1`:

```
SNP Chr Pos ID_01 ID_02 ...
rs01 1 200 AA BB ...
rs03 1 30 AA BB ...
```

**file25** will contain all the records whose 2nd field is `25`:

```
SNP Chr Pos ID_01 ID_02 ...
rs02 25 10 BA AA ...
```

And so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { hdr = $0; next }                     
    {
        if(!f[$2]) { print hdr >"file" $2; f[$2] = 1 }
        print >>"file" $2
    }' data.txt
```

Comment: @Cbhihe The initial question makes no reference to some records having only a single column.  Only your edit claims that, and it seems to be contrary to the OP's intent.

Comment: +1: My bad,  I must have dreamt it or been contaminated by another thread I was looking at in parallel... I see that OP is being edited to reflect the original request.  Thanks.